# i want to test if an event still has places, if yes the user can participate, im using node js api rest

Tags: mysql, node.js

i want to test if an event still has places, if yes the user can participate and the nbr_place zattribute will be decremented by 1,if not an error messsage "no more places" will be displayed, im using node js api rest, there is my code

the update sql request works fine, but the problem is on the test

```
/* UPDATE EVENT nbr place */
app.put('/participate/:id', (req, res) => {


    const id = req.params.id;
    //const nbr_place = req.params.nbr_place;
    con.query('SELECT nbr_place FROM evenement where  id_evenement=?',[id],function (err,result,fields) {
if (result && result.length)
            res.json('no more places');
        else {
            con.query('UPDATE evenement SET nbr_place = nbr_place - 1 WHERE id_evenement = ?', [id], (error, result) => {
                if (error) throw error;

                res.send('decremented successfully');
            });
        }
});
});
```

Comment: `res.json` is meant to output json data, but you are providing it a string. Instead, you might do something like `res.json({ error: 'no more places' });` if in fact you want the response to be in JSON format.

Comment: the problem is in this line '''if (result && result.length)''', how i test if nbr_place = or < 0

Comment: i want to test if 'nbr_place' = 0 so 'no more places' will be displayed, and if 'nbr_place' > 0 the user can participate so the update query will excute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not checking the value returned by the `SELECT` query (you are just checking if the query returned *something*).

But in terms of conception, running a `select` then an `update` creates a *race* condition, where, typically, two concurrent process might `select` the last remaining seat of an event, resulting in `-1` seat left.

A better solution would be to run a single `update` with a condition on the count of remaining seats, and then just check whether it succedeed (ie if a record was affected). With this technique, your database handles concurrency for you (and it is something databases are really good at).

Consider:

```
app.put('/participate/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    con.query(
        'UPDATE evenement SET nbr_place = nbr_place - 1 WHERE id_evenement = ? and nbr_place > 0',
        [id],
        function (err,result,fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
                res.send('decremented successfully');
            } else {
                res.json('no more places');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is in this line '''if (result && result.length)''', how i test if nbr_place = or < 0
>
> i want to test if 'nbr_place' = 0 so 'no more places' will be displayed, and if 'nbr_place' > 0 the user can participate so the update query will excute

In that case, all you need is the following:

```
con.query('SELECT nbr_place FROM evenement where  id_evenement=?',[id],function (err,result,fields) {
    if (err) {
        //handle error
    }

    if (result && result.length > 0) {
        if (result[0].nbr_place > 0) {
            //there are places
        } else {
            //there are no more places
        }
    }
    else {
        //no results returned
    }
});
```